# How can I change the font without changing the size?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{UITextAttributeTextColor: navTextColor,
 UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: navTextColor,
 UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],
 UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12]}];
```

That code changes the UINavigationBar's font to HelveticaNeue-Bold and set the size to 12.

What about if I do not want to set the size to 12. I just want the font to be HelveticaNeue

What should I do?

Comment: Get the font size it already has and use that?

Comment: That's one approach. So specifying font always specify the size too I guess and you can't decouple that. Now how do I know the default font size used by UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the font size by using titleTextAttributes, an NSDictionary on the UINavigationBar just added to iOS 5. Then just call `[navibar.titleTextAttributes objectForKey:UITextAttributeFont];` to get the UIFont of the title.